# WordPress Tinymce editor broken and nothing seems to fix it :(

Tags: tinymce

First off, i've tried stuff posted here already, didnt help.

Issue :

[image]

Here is what i tried 
Tried renaming htaccess
removing all plugins 
removing and reinstalling theme (there is only one ) 
tried diff wordpress theme 
tried reuploading the tinymce folder 
tried reuploading post.php

Nothing works so far,

Javascript console shows

[image]

Can someone assist? 
this is really getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by a regression in TinyMCE (which was updated in 4.9.6).

See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44134 for the fixes to go into 4.9.7.

Comment: I updated my tinymce from the site, yet no avail.